# RecyclerView ItemDecoration vs Margin for spacing between RecyclerView items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

So in my have I have *recyclerviews* and I want spacing between my *recyclerview* items, so here I have two options

1. I can subclass `RecyclerView.ItemDecoration`
2. I can add `margin` to the item itself

Cleary the second option is the easy one and using that option I am getting the desired result but over the web I see people using `ItemDecoration` for that and also recommends it.

I want to know is there some advantage of using `ItemDecoration` even if my use case is very simple like adding spacing between items?
will `ItemDecoration` provide performance benefits or other benefits?

Answer (score 3):

**Using `ItemDecoration`:**

1. Easy to implement, just `recyclerView.addItemDecoration(DividerItemDecoration(requireContext(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL))`
2. It's natural, it only adds the gap between items, which means you won't see it on the top of the first item, or the bottom of last item.
3. You can customize the divider, by following:

   ```
    val dividerDrawable = getDrawable(context, R.drawable.divider)

    itemDecoration.setDrawable(dividerDrawable)
   ```

---

**Using `Margin` on Item View Layout:**

1. Also easy to achieve, but it has some obvious drawback: **it will appear on the top of first item and the bottom of last item**. Unless you write more code (logic) to deal with it.

Answer (score 2):

What you've read across various resources is indeed true. Using `ItemDecoration` is much more **clean** and the code is **reusable** in some sense.

This eliminates our need to manually adjust the margins in the UI for the item_layout, even then also the topmost and the bottom most item contain margin issues.

Using `ItemDecoration` we can create a separate class (see below example) for adding offsets (aka. margins) which will automatically add the required spacing in between the `RecyclerView` items:

```
class MarginItemDecoration(private val spaceSize: Int) : RecyclerView.ItemDecoration() {
    override fun getItemOffsets(
        outRect: Rect, view: View,
        parent: RecyclerView, 
        state: RecyclerView.State
    ) {
        with(outRect) {
            if (parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view) == 0) {
                top = spaceSize
            }
            left = spaceSize
            right = spaceSize
            bottom = spaceSize
        }
    }
}
```

> Thanks to [@cmorigaki](https://gist.github.com/cmorigaki/d402403e3443cfefce11b071b9c0006d#file-marginitemdecoration-kt) for this above example.

Comment: This solution works, keep in mind though that bottom spacing is not conditional on the adapter position in the above logic and will result in extra spacing for the last element. It's easier to drop it altogether and just have the top one account for both.